# understanding looping real inference call

Tags: pytorch, gpu, nvidia, huggingface

I was looking for a solution for an issue I was having with my interface speed. I saw this [answer](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/inference-time-hugging-face-detr/274721) online but I don't understand what the solution was. The person is using a hugging face model with pytorch and the solution was to loop the real inference call to increase the GPU utilization. This was caused by a bottleneck from accessing the data. Can I get some help understanding how to implement this solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misinterpreting the post. It doesn't say that looping inference increases GPU utilization - it posits looping inference as a test to see if the bottleneck is loading data. It's a test, not a solution.

Looping inference loads data once, then runs inference multiple times, allowing you to see the GPU performance without i/o overhead. If GPU performance improves when looping inference, it indicates an i/o bottleneck.

Comment: ah okay, so pretty much it was just loading all the images into let say a dictionary and then getting them from there instead of reading it from the file each time? Also thanks for clarifying